# How do war elephants fight?

Tags: war, warfare, animals, tactics, war-elephants

Do they just run into a phalanx, breaking it up? Do they lift their front foot and then crush enemies below?

What do elephants do?

Or do the fighters on top of it just shoot arrows?

Comment: -1: This is explained in depth in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_elephant).

Comment: wikipedia doesn't specify how. What is trample damage? Does the elephant actually step on soldiers or just push push push

Comment: Elephants can do a lot of very nasty things with their heads, trunks and tusks - and even with their ears and their tails. An elephant that was armored and trained to attack would be a rather terrifying foe to face. (Although elephants are very intelligent and perhaps they are smart enough not to take to such training...)

Comment: What research have you done so far? - most SE sites prefer that you document your efforts to solve the problem before posting the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally they were used as as shock and awe (read: point and charge) cavalry would have been.  Of course, (horse) cavalry is much more versatile but did not have the same fear factor as elephants. They would sit on one flank and move to attack the side of the enemy's phalanx where they would do the most damage. Clearly, this was a dangerous tactic since elephants were prone to panic and run amok.  Another formation, like at Zama, they were used in the initial phase of the battle to try to shatter the formations of the enemy's army.

Mostly, they were fear factors against the enemy army and not that useful in the battle -- although, there are a [few battles](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/338/war-elephants-in-battles) where they were decisive in winning.

Comment: Horses tended to really dislike being around elephants, so they were pretty effective against cavalry.

Comment: Elephants are slow. Also why Hannibal send Elephant early? He should have let the infantry fight and then use the elephant to screw enemies formation.

Comment: @JimThio: As I said: *to try to shatter the formations of the enemy's army.*

Comment: Because Elephants were much harder to control, they really weren't used "as cavalry would have been".  They're more of a blunt instrument, point them at a target of opportunity and charge, once the chaos of battle got to them they'd be impossible to control, unlike horses.

Comment: @Odysseus: Cavalry is used as a "point at target and charge".  What makes horses superior to elephants is that they are easier to keep under control -- just like my answers states.  Elephants were mostly used as a fear weapon those deployment was closest to cavalry.

Comment: @Sardathrion Cavalry can be point and charge but it's also capable of flanking, baiting, skirmishing, withdrawing, and a host of other complicated maneuvers. Cavalry was also a common element in most armies, war elephants were always a novelty, that was part of their power. The answer is pretty solid but given that "War Elephants == Big Cavalry" is an extremely common misconception I think more emphasis needs to be put on their unique role and varying utilization rather than conflating them with cavalry.

Comment: AH! I see what you mean now!  Answer edited.

Comment: and of course elephants with their larger size and strength can help in the construction of large siege works outside of battle, their use as instruments of battle may have been secondary rather than primary in the initial decision to include them in the ranks of an army.

Comment: @jwenting: If you were to add some source to your comment, it would make for a good answer. ^_~

Comment: is it the case that there would be a significant case of "what on earth is that?" before the actual "charge" of an elephant? Lots of opponents would never have even seen one before. I wonder if we sometimes forget this.